# Can I substitute Gaggia Descaler for Sage 'the Descaler'?

Tags: cleaning, coffee-machines

Having recently replaced a Gaggia Platinum Swing Up with a [Sage the Oracle](http://www.sageappliances.co.uk/the-oracle.html), I have some [Gaggia Descaler](http://www.gaggia-parts.co.uk/epages/es147467.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/es147467/Products/21001682) left over.

Is it possible to substitute this for the [the Descaler](http://www.sageappliances.co.uk/descaler.html) that the Sage machine uses? If so, how would I go about doing so?

The chemical composition of the Gaggia Descaler is (proportions unspecified):

- Citric acid
- Lactic acid
- Corrosion inhibitor

*(Yes, there's a double 'the' in there. It is called 'the Descaler', presumably as the appliance it's used with is called 'the Oracle')*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Gaggia Descaler would work fine in any espresso machine. Just use the same procedure and amount that worked for the Gaggia machine (or use the directions for The Oracle).

I have never bothered to buy any commercial descaler, since they seem overpriced to me. I buy pure citric acid powder over the internet, and use that for both a Gaggia Classic and a Ponte Vecchio Lusso.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE! Do you know anything about the actual value of the corrosion inhibitor, which is a common additive to descalers? Pour understanding of it always stopped me from just using citric acid.

Comment: I know nothing about "corrosion inhibitor". My Gaggia Classic has had no corrosion problems, and I have only used citric acid to descale it.